# Trying to render data from database with a model in Django but it's showing operationError

Tags: python, django

**Inside product app in views.py**

```
'''
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Person

def product_details(request,*args, **kwargs):
    obj=Person.objects.get(id=1)
    context={
    'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, "productH/detail.html", context)
'''
```

**Inside Templete I've made a new folder 'productH', and inside productH I made detail.html**
**Inside detail.html**

```
'''
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>
    {{object.title}}
</h1>

<p>
    this is showing detail.html file
</p>
{% endblock %}
'''
```

**after this in url.py I've added**

```
'''
from Products.view import person
url={
    path('product/', product_details)
    }
'''
```

**inside model I've coded**

```
'''
[from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
     
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    roll_no = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    total_marks = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
'''
```

[this Error is occuring.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0njR8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe you forget to migrate your database. Please try this command in your terminal before hit the endpoint.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I've tried to migrate several times, but then also it's showing the same Error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem is how you are writing your URLs. If your app is named `product` then you should import it like this

```py
from product import views

urls=[
    path('product/', views.product_details)
]
```

Comment: Both the methods are same, and will give the same output. here's nothing to do with it.

Comment: If your app is called `Products`, then you should import `views` instead of `view` and then use the methods `product_detail()`. Instead, you are importing `person` which is your model and is not part of `views.py`. Also, it has a typo because your models is called `Person` with capital. And for convention your app should be all lowercase `products`